# ASP.NET SOAP Webservice ,Encode Problem in Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Here is my problem, Im trying to Encode the response of my webservice with the following Code.

```
public static string ConvertToUTF8(string Cadena)
    {
        string mensajeex = Cadena;
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(mensajeex);
        // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, utf8, unicodeBytes);
        // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
        char[] asciiChars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
        utf8.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
        string Utf8string = new string(asciiChars);
        // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", mensajeex);
        Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", Utf8string);
        return Utf8string;

  }
```

And actually it works! But when I try to Encode a string and then pass through an exception as a Message property like this

```
throw new Exception(XMLHelper.ConvertToUTF8(Message));
```

It give me the response wrong like:

```
El valor &#39;R&#39; no es v&#225;lido seg&#250
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does that translate to in English?

Comment: It means that the value isnt valid. Btw the problem is that the response dosent apear encoded correctly. As u can see the chars &#39;R&#39; should be leters decoded .